# Counting len() of BTree saved in ZODB takes much time

Tags: python, zodb

I use ZODB coupled with `BTree`s to store a large amount of data (millions of keys). I'd like to get the exact number of entries in my root dictionary (which is a `BTree`). As I noticed, `len()` called on the result of `.keys()` takes a very long time (tens of minutes at least, honestly I've never waited for it to end when data set grew larger).

```
import ZODB
from BTrees.OOBTree import BTree

connection = ZODB.connection('database.fs')
dbroot = connection.root()

if not hasattr(dbroot, 'dictionary'):
    dbroot.dictionary = BTree()

# much data is added and transactions are commited

number_of_items = len(dbroot.dictionary.keys()) # takes very long time
```

I pack the DB regularly.

I don't think it's relevant to the question, but `dbroot.dictionary` contains other `BTree`s inside as values.

Comment: Why are you calling `keys`?

Comment: Honestly I don't know. That could be the issue. I'll check.

Comment: @Luke: it absolutely is the issue.

Comment: If you are storing more btrees in the btree, did you want the *total length* of all those trees or just of the outermost `dictionary` btree?

Comment: @MartijnPieters only the outermost

Comment: @MartijnPieters but you could mention also how to, for example, count all subitems (on the second level of the tree) if there's some other method than to iterate over every value on the first level and call `len`.

Comment: @Luke: that'll take longer still. You'd have to iterate over the `Btree.values()` list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are calling the `.keys()` method which must load and produce a full list of all the keys. *That* takes a lot of time.

You could ask the length of the BTree *itself*:

```
number_of_items = len(dbroot.dictionary)
```

This still needs to [load all the buckets themselves](https://github.com/zopefoundation/BTrees/blob/master/BTrees/BTreeTemplate.c#L2317-L2331) (blocks of keys) to ask each for its length, so this still has to load a lot of data, just not produce the list.

We've always avoided trying to get a direct length; the [`Btree.Length` object](https://github.com/zopefoundation/BTrees/blob/master/BTrees/Length.py) is better suited for keeping track of a length 'manually'. The object is fully ZODB conflict-resolving. Each time you add elements to `dbroot.dictionary`, add a count to the `BTree.Length` object and have it keep count:

```
from BTrees.OOBTree import BTree
from BTrees.Length import Length

if not hasattr(dbroot, 'dictionary'):
    dbroot.dictionary = BTree()
    dbroot.dict_length = Length()

# add objects into the dictionary? Add to the length as well:
for i in range(count):
    dbroot.dictionary[keys[i]] = value[i]
dbroot.dict_length.change(count)
```

then read out the length by calling the object:

```
length = dbroot.dict_length()
```

Comment: I tried `len(dbroot.actions_values)`. It's been over ten minutes now and it's still working.

Comment: @Luke: ah, right, calculating the length is indeed [proportional to the buckets](https://github.com/zopefoundation/BTrees/blob/master/BTrees/BTreeTemplate.c#L2317).

Comment: @Luke: sorry, it's been a few years since I used ZODB BTrees in earnest, added a work-around for the issue.

Comment: In order to use a workaround I'd have to remodel my code. Sometimes I add new nodes, sometimes I just change data inside existing ones. But I guess there's no other option.